# Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am new to react.in my new project I am getting an error after using redux in the project. The app was working perfectly before integrating redux to it. i have added the store,action and reducer files and when i try to add it to a component its showing me this error.

Here is the funtion that i want to add redux to.

```
function Addproduct() {

const navigate = useNavigate();

const { values, setFieldValue, errors, touched, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit} = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    validationSchema: addproductSchema,
    onSubmit: (vḁl̥u̥es,{resetForm}) => {
        
        console.log('vḁl̥u̥es: ', vḁl̥u̥es);
        resetForm()
        
    }
})



const PostAdd = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const products=useSelector((state)=> state)
    const dispatch=useDispatch()

    const { brandname, productname, picture, quantity, price, description } = values;

    const email = localStorage.getItem('email')

    await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/addproduct", {
        brandname, productname, quantity, price, description, email
    })

        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            window.alert("Product added successfully")
            dispatch(addProduct(response.data))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.response)
            window.alert("Error adding Product Details")
        })
}
```

Reducer file:

```
const initialState = {
products: []
}


 export const productReducer = 
 (state=initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.ADD_PRODUCTS:
        return {...state,products:payload}
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

Action file:

```
export const addProduct = (products) =>{
return {
    type:ActionTypes.ADD_PRODUCTS,
    payload:products
    
}
}
```

i have no idea what am i doing wrong here.

my react-dom version is 18.2..

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `hooks` must be used in `React Functional components` not simple function.

Comment: Are you using any asynchronous action middleware, like Thunks, or using Redux-Toolkit? You can't use React hooks in Redux action creators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I see now, `AddProduct` is the React component and you are trying to use some React hooks in the `PostAdd` function. just move the hooks out to the function component body.

Example:

```
function Addproduct() {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state); // <-- here
  const dispatch = useDispatch();                 // <-- here

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {
    values,
    setFieldValue,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleBlur,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    validationSchema: addproductSchema,
    onSubmit: (vḁl̥u̥es, { resetForm }) => {
      console.log('vḁl̥u̥es: ', vḁl̥u̥es);
      resetForm();
    }
  });

  const postAdd = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { brandname, productname, picture, quantity, price, description } = values;

    const email = localStorage.getItem('email')

    await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/addproduct", {
      brandname, productname, quantity, price, description, email
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        window.alert("Product added successfully")
        dispatch(addProduct(response.data))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(err.response)
        window.alert("Error adding Product Details")
      });
  };
```